# A lot of space at the beginning of the page in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

[image: This is the table of contents]

There is a lot of space in the beginning which I do no like. And also to other sections (but only the start page of the section). Do you guys have any clue on how to reduce the vertical space between the header and the actual content.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{headings}

%page layout
\setlength{\voffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{210mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{7mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\parindent 10mm
\parskip 5mm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redeclare the sectioning command which you'd like to change and set whatever `beforeskip` you like:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openany]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{headings}


\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}

%page layout
\setlength{\voffset}{0mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{210mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{7mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\parindent 10mm
\parskip 5mm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer courtesy of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62125/how-to-remove-top-margin-above-tableofcontents. Visit this excellent post to get a comprehensive explanation and alternative methods to do your stuff.**

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\begingroup%
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}% <cmd>
    {\vspace*{50\p@}}% <search>
    {}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \oldtableofcontents%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

The above does a local search-and-replace within @makeschapterhead (replacing \vspace*{50\p@} with nothing, before calling the regular table of contents. The redefinition (search-and-replace) is localized within the scope of the group.